# Token price chart with ethers.js

Tags: ethers.js, binance-smart-chain

Right now I'm using Ethers.js to get the token price from BSC successfully using this code.

```
  const pairContract = new ethers.Contract(pairAddress, pancakePair, provider);
  const reserves = await pairContract.getReserves();
```

I want to create a price chart for that token, but I get into trouble when don't know how to get the historical price data from BSC.

Any idea?

Comment: You can get the BSC price chart data feeds and open source code for creating charts from my project: https://tradingstrategy.ai/trading-view

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa, thanks for the suggestion; your project is magnification. But I am trying to learn about Ethers.JS and how things work. Are there any other solutions I should look at? Thanks for your comment.

Comment: You can find most of the Python code to pull BSC data here: https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/smart-contracts-for-testing